# Does the verb 'deliver' make sense in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, tenses, sentence-fragments

We are going to deliver this meeting.

Not sure if the verb 'deliver' is used correctly in this sentence.  If not what alternative words can I use?

Answer (score 4):

As a non-native speaker, the OP should probably avoid the usage. But if I saw those words written by someone I knew was a competent speaker/writer, I wouldn't have a problem understanding it as an *emphatic* assertion meaning something along the lines of...

> *We're fully confident that we **will** be able to ensure this meeting does in fact take place [even if appearances might suggest it won't].*

It's contextually implicit that the group represented by "we" are the people *responsible* for arranging the meeting, who'd be deemed to have *failed* if the meeting didn't take place (if we didn't [***deliver the goods***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/deliver-the-goods)).

---

Note that *meetings* are usually *held, arranged, hosted,...* rather than *delivered*. But the latter term is "contextually licensed" in the exact cited context, where it's implicitly necessary to *overcome adverse circumstances* to ensure the meeting does in fact take place.

Answer (score 0):

For a meeting you do not use this verb; it is proper for terms such as "lecture" and "speech".

A meeting is not the sort of thing that a single person or even a group of persons can handle as to what will precisely go on in it: it is something that has a life of its own and may evolve in many directions, even in some rare occasions degenerate into  a brawl.

So, a meeting can be organized, can take place, can be (among other possible verbal locutions). If you want to relate to the action of people participating to a meeting you have to use other verbs, and the choice will depend  on who is concerned: participate to , go through with a/the meeting (esp. if it is difficult or unpleasant), preside at a/the meeting, be present at a/the meeting,…

Comment: As FF says, 'deliver' = 'come through with' licenses the usage with DO 'meeting'. But it's rare, and doesn't mean unmarked 'hold'.

Comment: So I can say 'We are going to preside this meeting'.  Can I say, 'We are going to conduct this meeting?

Comment: @Denver If you belong to the group that is going to provide some control in the proceedings of the meeting (preliminary information to the participants, etc.), certainly, you can use "conduct"; as to "preside", it is usually the prerogative of only one person to do that, and in most cases that person is important in the domain of activity that the meeting concerns; however,  the control provided by a president has to do with the proceedings themselves (propose the themes for discussion, moderate the debate, etc.).

Comment: One *holds* a meeting.

Comment: Thanks Xanne that's the word I was looking for!!!

Comment: @Xanne You do say "conduct a meeting" too:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22conduct%20a%20meeting%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en What this book will do is prepare you to conduct a meeting of which you and your organization can be proud https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Chairing_a_Meeting_with_Confidence/aEK5AAAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22conduct+a+meeting%22&dq=%22conduct+a+meeting%22&printsec=frontcover